# Why double curly brackets in `\long\def\bold#1{{\bf#1}}`

Tags: plain-tex, definition

I'm reading The TeXbook by Knuth.

Page 205 has

> If you actually want a control sequence to allow arguments with \par
> tokens, you can deﬁne it to be a “long” macro by saying ‘\long’ just
> before ‘\def’. For example, the \bold macro deﬁned by
>
> `\long\def\bold#1{{\bf#1}}`
>
> is capable of setting several paragraphs in boldface type...

I tried to have only one set of curly brackets. It worked with no problems.

```
\long\def\bold#1{\bf#1}

\bold{Hello

world}
```

Why did Knuth write two sets of curly brackets in `{{\bf#1}}`. Are there any corner cases?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With the definition

```
\long\def\bold#1{\bf#1}
```

`\bold{hello world}` is simply expanded to `\bf hello world`, so `\bf` is applied not only to the argument of `\bold`, but also to what follows. Indeed, consider the following example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\long\def\bold#1{\bf#1}
\begin{document}
\bold{Hello

world}

Hello world
\end{document}
```

This outputs
[image]
which is obviously not the intended result.

Adding the second pair of curly brackets allows to restrict `\bf` to the argument of `\bold`.